# Javascript - delete table row that also recalculates totals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which allows users to make some selections and enter some numbers, which are then used to calculate the totals automatically. I've recently added some functionality to add additional rows to the table and also allow the users to delete a row if required.

I need the Delete button to also force a recalculation of the totals at the same time, whereas at present it's just delete the row and leaving the original totals which are now incorrect.

Here's my script to delete the table row:

```
$(window).load(function(){
//Sum Table Cell and Map

 $('#lastYear')
    .on('change', 'select', calc)
    .on('keyup', 'input', calc);

function calc(){

    $('#lastYear tr:has(.risk)').each(function(i,v){

        var $cel = $(v.cells);

        var $risk = $cel.eq(1).find('option:selected').val();
        var $numb = $cel.eq(2).find('input').val();
        var $weeks = $cel.eq(3).find('input').val();
        var $avg = ($numb * $weeks) / 52;
        var $avgRounded = Math.round( $avg * 10 ) / 10;

        $cel.eq(4).find('input').val($avgRounded);

    });   

    var tot = {high:0,moderate:0}; 

    $('#lastYear tr:has(.risk) option:selected')
                .map(function(i){
                    var el = $(this).val();
                    var qty = parseFloat(
$('#lastYear tr:has(.risk)').eq(i).find('td:last')
    .prev().prev() // call prev method twice
    .find('input').val()
);

                    if (!tot.hasOwnProperty(el)) {
                        tot[el] = 0;            
                    }
                    tot[el] += qty
                    return tot;
                }).get();

    // console.log(tot);
     $('#textfield4').val(tot.moderate.toFixed(1));
    $('#textfield5').val(tot.high.toFixed(1));

    }
});//]]>
```

and here's the script that does the calculations:

```
$('#lastYear').on('click', '.delbtn', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove()
});

var newIDSuffix = 2;
$('#lastYear').on('click', '.addbtn', function () {
    var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
    $(thisRow).find('.delbtn').show();

    var cloned = $(thisRow).clone();
    cloned.find('input, select').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.substring(0, id.length - 1) + newIDSuffix;
        $(this).attr('id', id);
    });

    cloned.insertAfter(thisRow).find('input:text').val('');
    cloned.find('.delbtn').hide();
    cloned.find("[id^=lastYearSelect]")
    .autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        select: function (e, ui) {

            $(e.target).val(ui.item.value);
            setDropDown.call($(e.target));
        }
    }).change(setDropDown);

    $(this).remove();
    newIDSuffix++;
});
```

I've setup a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmdataweb/6KPxq/1/) which might help explain what's going on.

I'm new to Javascript but to me it looks like I somehow need to combine the delete function with the calculate function somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call `calc()` in your `.delbtn` click handler. The `calc` function and the delete button click handler are in different contexts at the moment ... but if they were in the same scope (move them into the same file and same `onload` block), you'd be fine.

I've updated your JSFiddle to demonstrate http://jsfiddle.net/6KPxq/2/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#lastYear').on('click', '.delbtn', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    calc();
});
```